# Manjaro/Arch downgrade to specific version of package

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro, pacman

I need to install a specific version of Firefox so that I can reproduce and fix a bug in a web app.

I read [this article](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-install-an-older-package-version/2603/8) and installed `downgrade`. However, when I run...

```
sudo DOWNGRADE_FROM_ALA=1 downgrade firefox
```

...it only goes back to version 58, and I need version 56. Any way to go back even farther?